# json.swift file is error [let str:String? = NSString(contentsOfURL:nsurl, usedEncoding:&enc) as? String]

Tags: json, swift

Please have previously also allowed to question because although I was allowed to question not yet resolved

Errors such as the photo came out in json.swift

version of xcode is 7.0.1

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cast NSString(contentsOfURL:...) to String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32263893/cast-nsstringcontentsofurl-to-string)

Answer (score 0):

For swift 2.0 it should be:

```
do {
        let str: String? = try NSString(contentsOfURL: nsurl, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as String
        print(str)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.description)
    }
```

You can read more about Error handling [HERE](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/new-syntax-swift-2-error-handling-try-catch).